# How to communicate over USB using libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I would like to communicate over USB between my android tablet (libgdx game) and an arduino device (using serial com).

Does libgdx support to send and receive data over usb natively ? If not, I probably need to create my own [InputProcessor](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html) implementation based on [Android USB Host API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) ?

Comment: That's a specific platform code, you can run with Lbgdx but that has nothing to do with the API, search the ways to do it with android, create an interface and implement it on desktop, android and ios getting the data you want, note that input processor is for user input like touch, click, nothing prevents you implement it but it will be a lot of work anyway, why not create a USBInputProcessor of your own?

Comment: Yes, that my question (native usb support like controller/input device). So I need to implement my own.

Comment: I recommend you to take a look at com.badlogic.gdx.controllers [class](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjY5fi5z67LAhVFGx4KHdT6BQ0QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Flibgdx%2Flibgdx%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2Fextensions%2Fgdx-controllers%2Fgdx-controllers%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fbadlogic%2Fgdx%2Fcontrollers%2FControllers.java&usg=AFQjCNHdvxiLQcfwJB6ONONgB0j6PkzC9Q&sig2=_irl_qx1r0XXkccYMGXGHQ&bvm=bv.116274245,d.dmo), you will have a good start on how to implement it on your own.

Comment: Controllers seems working only for HID devices. Any idea how to add my own controller to controller manager ?